# Is this an improved implementation of selection sort?

Tags: java, selection-sort

```
public class SelectionSort {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] intArray = {20, 35, -15, 7, 55, 1, -22};
        int largest = 0;
        int iteration = 0;
        int indexLargest = 0;
        int temp = 0;

        for (int idx = intArray.length - 1; idx > 0; idx--){
            if(intArray[idx] > largest){
                largest = intArray[idx];
                indexLargest = idx;
            }
            
            if(idx == 1){
                iteration++;

                temp = intArray[intArray.length - iteration];
                intArray[intArray.length - iteration] = largest;
                intArray[indexLargest] = temp;
                
                largest = 0;
                idx = intArray.length - iteration;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am just curious what the big-O notation is of the above code. The code is not 100% functional since it does not include the first index, I just made it as a proof of concept.

The most generic implementation of selection sort is O(n^2), but I was curious if it was possible this implementation is an improvement?

I am just learning about big-O and this is purely a conceptual implementation.

Comment: What makes you think it might be an improvement? What change have you made from a regular selection sort?

Comment: forgoing the typical 2nd for loop

Comment: So i am trying to grasp why this would still be a O(n^2), if it is just one loop

Comment: You alter the loop variable `idx` inside the body of the loop, so the loop you do have is not N iterations long.

Comment: You appear to be under the misconception that an algorithm with one loop must be O(n). This is not true; your loop iterates O(n^2) times.

Comment: How about you count the number of times your loop actually iterates and see if it behaves like O(n) ?

Comment: So essentially this implementation is just harder to read and has no viable improvement is what I'm hearing here. Is it a bad assumption to assume there will never be an implementation of selection sort that will be < n^2?

Comment: It would not be selection sort.

Comment: Got it. So selection sort is useless lol. I am going to look into it now, because I do not know why someone would want to use it. Thanks for the feedback!